# I get a 401 'Unauthorized' error despite User being saved in DB

Tags: node.js, passport.js, session-cookies, passport-local

I get a 401 'Unauthorized' being sent through even on new user being created.

I've tried refactoring my code many times and checking SO as well as Googleing all over but with no success.

**user.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**auth.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');

router.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());

const User = require("../models/user");

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', { title: 'Casa Lugano Immobiliare SA | Registrati' });
})

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {

    User.register({ username: req.body.username }, 'password', (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.redirect('/register');
        } else {
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () => {
                console.log('user authenticated')
                res.redirect('/');
            })
        }
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DB', { useNewUrlParser: true });

//REQUIRING ROUTES
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
app.use(authRoute);
```

I would like the user to be authenticated after registration! I've been stuck for many hours so any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug, I had to pass an User object instead of the username only:

```
User.register({ username: req.body.username }
```

becomes:

```
const newUser = new User({ username: req.body.username });
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function (err, user) { [...]
```

Thanks for the attention!